# Prototype search by attributes values

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, javascript-framework

I would like to have the equivalence of the jquery `$("element[attribute='value']");` or `$("element").find("[attribute='value']");` but in Prototype.
This searches an element that has a specific attribute value.
It must be quite easy but I don't know much of Prototype and I don't find any answers anywhere.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$$` in Prototype

```
$$("element[attribute='value']")
```

Comment: What a fast reply. I think I got a misunderstanding of the basics, I have this: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="22">` I need to search rel="22" but here if I do `$$("a[rel='22']").hide()` it throws me `TypeError: Object javascript:void(0); has no method 'hide'`

Comment: Try: `$$("element[attribute='value']")[0].hide()`

Comment: That did the trick ! Ok so the difference with jQuery is that we need to be precise on the element, jQuery will just hide all. Thank you very much (2min to accept your reply)

Comment: Glad it worked! My prototype is rusty so I wasn't 100% sure i remembered it correctly.

Comment: I'm forced to use it because of Magento :-( But I don't want to. Thank you again :-)